# UITableView with UIWebVIew Not Loading UIWebView. Does It Require an IBAction?

Tags: uitableview, uiwebview

This is the code I've got so far, basically what's supposed to happen is that once you make a selection in the UITableView, you should then get a transition that will take you onto the UIWebView although all that's happening is once you make a selection it just highlights blue.

***First view controller .h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YoMaFifthViewController : UITableViewController

{

NSArray *data, *sites;
}


@end
```

***First view controller .m***

```
#import "YoMaFifthViewController.h"
#import "YoMaWebsiteViewController.h"

@interface YoMaFifthViewController ()

@end

@implementation YoMaFifthViewController



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

#pragma mark - view lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Website", @"Developer", nil];
sites = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
         @"https://www.google.co.uk/",
         @"https://www.google.co.uk/",
         nil];


// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [data count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [sites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;





}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:      (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}   
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
}   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
YoMaWebsiteViewController *wvc = [[YoMaWebsiteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YoMaWebsiteViewController" bundle:nil];
wvc.site = [sites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:wvc animated:YES];

}




@end
```

***Website view controller .h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YoMaWebsiteViewController : UIViewController
{

IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;

}

@property (retain) NSString *site;


@end
```

***Website view controller .m***

```
#import "YoMaWebsiteViewController.h"

@interface YoMaWebsiteViewController ()

@end

@implementation YoMaWebsiteViewController
@synthesize site;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.site];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Is your table view controller inside a navigation controller?  Set a breakpoint in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and check the value of self.navigationController.  I bet it's nil.

Answer (score 0):

You would need an IB Action or a segue to the website view controller (for static cells). When it comes to dynamic prototypes, a segues would work. You can do the segues with a little bit of code. First, go to the storyboard and <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from the First View Controller to the Website View Controller (use the icons on the bottom or use the document outline). Then, after giving the segue an identifier, use the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifier" sender:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
}
```

**Edit 2:** If you're using a xib do this (no control drag):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerNameHere animated:YES sender:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
}
```

Comment: I'm not using storyboards, I'm using .xib's

Comment: Just use this: `[self presentModalViewController:otherViewCon animated:YES];`

Comment: You can't use that because `presentmodalviewcontroller animated` is deprecated in iOS 6, when I go to add that line it's lined out in red, also you didn't expect me to control drag did you?

Comment: Unfortunately no fix, I'm now getting an error that reads `No visible @interface for 'UINavigationController' declares the selector 'pushViewController:animated:sender`

Comment: Unfortunately, that's all I got. I don't usually use XIB so I can't really help you further. I apologize.